# How to draw a decorated rectangle with rounded corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf

As the title says, I was trying to draw a rectangle with rounded corners, and then decided it needed decorating. Well, the result looks awesome, but isn't really what I had in mind.
a) What happened?
b) How do I do it properly?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[rounded corners=40mm,
           decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=5,segment length=30}]
    (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...talk about `pathmorphing` a rectangle... into a bird's nest! `tikz`-tastic! Remove the `snake`, which bird's don't enjoy anyway, in order to fix the problem. `:)`

Comment: "I see it, but I don't believe it.".  So I ran the code myself and can confirm that that genuinely is what one obtains.  Totally bizarre.  If this is a bug, I sincerely hope that they never fix it as that is a fantastic picture.

Comment: I think we should call it a feature. Amazing!

Comment: Hahah, amazing indeed. Here is a microprocessor : `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[rounded corners=1cm,
           decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=5mm,segment length=3}]
    (0,0) rectangle (5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}`. Crazy stuff

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*Update 2022-08-24: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655154/86 has a different method for disabling the `rounded corners` before the decoration starts that is probably a better overall method. The explanation below is still relevant, though.*

The problem is that the `rounded corners` option is getting applied to the result of the decoration.  So you need to turn it off after the initial path is constructed but before the decoration is applied.  This cannot be done in the `decoration` key because the options for that are actually processed when this key is originally parsed (ie at the start of the path).  So putting `/tikz/sharp corners` in the `decoration` simply negates the `rounded corners`.

Decorating the path is the very next thing done after the path has been processed so it's hard to stick something in between the path being constructed and being decorated!  However, it is possible and I'll present two ways.  The first works by splitting the construction into two pieces.  First we construct the rounded rectangle.  We do not draw it, but we save it.  Then we decorate it in a completely different command.  This separates the construction from the decoration and means that the scope of the `rounded corners` option is over by the time we get to the decoration.

The second way works because TikZ (or PGF) constructs a path *as it reads it*, rather than saving everything for the end.  This means that it is possible to insert options in the middle of the path and have them take effect from that point on (this only applies to options that affect how the path is constructed, not how it is rendered (so colour doesn't work)).  We basically want to turn off `rounded corners` at the end of the path so we do precisely that: at the end of the path we put `[sharp corners]`.  Then by the time the decoration is processed, we no longer round corners.

The second method is simpler, but the first is more powerful.  Indeed, it's the idea behind my `spath` library (still in alpha - indeed, looking at the code for this answer showed that that library lacks a few essential pieces): namely that a path can be *defined* and *used* in two different places.

With all that, here's the code (note that the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` piece is only needed for the first of the two solutions):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38989/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  use path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % First method: define and then use
 \path[rounded corners=30mm,save path=\rectpath]
    (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
 \draw[use path=\rectpath,
    decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=5,segment length=5}] (0,0);
 % Second solution: sharp corners at the end
 \draw[rounded corners=30mm,
    decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=5,segment length=5}]
    (0,9) rectangle +(8,8) [sharp corners];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: rounded corners with decoration]

As I said in my comment, I hope that even if they fix this then they provide a way to turn it back on as the original picture - whilst not what you want - is quite fun!  I especially like the fact that the `snake` decoration turns into a `birds nest`.

*See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655147/86 if trying to use this inside a `to path`*