# TikZ: Filled area with curvy end line

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

How can I have a filled area like this:

[image]

With a curvy line.
In the sense of: it continues here

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\filldraw[fill=cyan] (0,0) -- (250:2) arc (250:250+44:2) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, do you want the first shape with the irregular side filled? Why do you mention a curve that continues?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Morphing only a part of a full path in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79977/4778)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with `decorate`

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
curvy/.style={
rounded corners=1pt, 
% 1. version
fill, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=6mm, amplitude=0.75mm}, 
% 2. version
%fill, decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=4mm, amplitude=3mm}, 
},
]
\filldraw[fill=cyan] (0,0) to (250:2) arc (250:250+44:2) decorate[curvy] {--(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```