# TikZ/pgf: Path decorations look broken when using `rounded corners`

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's an example with `snake`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

\tikz [rounded corners]
    \graph [spring layout, node distance=25mm]
    {
        a ->[decorate, decoration=snake]
        b -> 
        c ->
        a ->
        e -> 
        b
    };

\end{document}
```

[image: snake]

Here's an example with `zigzag`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

\tikz [rounded corners]
    \graph [spring layout, node distance=25mm]
    {
        a ->[decorate, decoration=zigzag]
        b -> 
        c ->
        a ->
        e -> 
        b
    };

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why are the decorated paths not rendered correctly? I promise I have not mixed up the images for `snake` and `zigzag`. Try rendering them yourself.

Comment: Try removing `rounded corners` here rather than there!

Comment: @cfr That works like a charm! Would you like to write up an answer so that I can give you internet points?

Comment: Done as requested. Glad it worked!

Comment: More detail on what's going on is at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `rounded corners` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

\tikz %[rounded corners] remove this
    \graph [spring layout, node distance=25mm]
    {
        a ->[decorate, decoration=snake]
        b ->
        c ->
        a ->
        e ->
        b
    };

\end{document}
```

[image: snake]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

\tikz %[rounded corners] remove this
    \graph [spring layout, node distance=25mm]
    {
        a ->[decorate, decoration=zigzag]
        b ->
        c ->
        a ->
        e ->
        b
    };

\end{document}
```

[image: zigzag]

Here's a basic demonstration which doesn't use the `graphdrawing` library just to show this is an effect of using `rounded corners` with decorations which rely on short line segments (I think):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) [decorate, decoration=snake] -> (1,0);
    \draw (0,-.25) [decorate, decoration=zigzag] -> (1,-.25);
    \draw (0,-.5) [decorate, decoration=snake, rounded corners] -> (1,-.5);
    \draw (0,-.75) [decorate, decoration=zigzag, rounded corners] -> (1,-.75);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal demo]

Comment: Why does removing `rounded corners` solve the issue?

Comment: @user89 I'm not sure but on pp 151-2 of the `tikz` manual it mentions that `rounded corners` has pitfalls. One of these is that if the line segments are very short, it may cause 'inadvertent effects' which I suspect is what you are seeing ;). By the way, it has nothing to do with use of the `graphdrawing` library. You can reproduce it using just the `decorations.pathmorphing` library and drawing a couple of horizontal lines. If you want to keep `rounded corners` for the picture, you can use `sharp corners` when you need to switch the effect off temporarily.

Comment: Ah! I will try to rename the question then so that the focus isn't on the `graphdrawing` library.

Comment: @user89 I've also added an example which doesn't load any other `tikz` libraries but demonstrates the difference `rounded corners` makes.

Comment: if the path that needs to be rounded is shorter than the radius of the corner then an arc is drawn blindly and the path jumps back to the original corner.