# How to make text masking background shape lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, transparency

I want to draw a picture with some text masking the background shape lines. I tried with opacity but the fill is not very nature.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, convert, usenames, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm] (a) {};
    \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm, right = 1cm of a] (b) {};
    \draw [->, >=latex] (a) to node [above, fill, opacity=0.2,text opacity=1] {HelloWorld} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yield the following
[image]

However what I want is like this

[image]

Forget the background color, i use some image editing tool to get this. What I want is that part of rectangle shape line dissolved behind the text. I tried to use `backgrounds` but it also don't work.

Is there a possible solution?

Comment: `fill=white,fill opacity=1`?

Comment: `fill=white` will mask the arrow line below. `yshift` may be added as a workaround. But I am wondering if there are some elegant way of "fill of no color", it is better that it only mask the lines intersecting with the text

Comment: `\documentclass[border=5mm, convert, usenames, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm] (a) {};
    \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm, right = 1cm of a] (b) {};
    \path  (a) to node [above, fill=white] {HelloWorld} (b);
    \draw [-latex] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Yeah, first text then arrow line is a good solution. But I still want to know if there are any chance that `fill=white` can be replaced with things like `fill=nocolor` so that I can use the generated png in any color background

Comment: Not really. You could draw the node first, use `save path` and `use path` (from [this answer](ttps://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799)) to define the `reverseclip` trick (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799)) to spare out the node when drawing the boxes. A corresponding `ERASER` style has been defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448925).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `behind path` is what you are looking for. With `behind path` option node contents is drawn behind the path where it is defined (see example on page 214). This way `fill=white` will cover the lines and the arrow is drawn over the text.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, convert, usenames, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm] (a) {};
    \node [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm, right = 1cm of a] (b) {};
    \draw [->, >=latex] (a) to node [above, fill=white, behind path] {HelloWorld} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, `behind path` is one option I don't know before, quite useful here

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I take you want to block out the node. One way to do that is based on [save path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799), [reverseclip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448925).

```
\documentclass[convert, usenames, dvipsnames,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799
\tikzset{
  use path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{block out/.style={save path=\tmprotect}}% 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={([xshift=\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=\pgflinewidth/2,]current bounding box.north
        east) rectangle ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]current bounding box.south west)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm] (a) {};
 \node [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm, right = 1cm of a] (b) {};
 \draw [->, >=latex] (a) to node [above, block out] {HelloWorld} (b);   
 \clip[use path=\tmprotect,reverseclip]; 
 \draw (a.south west) rectangle (a.north east)
 (b.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems the magic happens when applying `insert path` to `clip`, and it now becomes outsider(reverse) clip. I read the manual about `insert path` and it says it "add something to the current path". How to understand it in this case?