# Intersection between sets in a Venn diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I would like the intersection of sets P and Q to be white as in the attached figure.

[image]

My command is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, mathrsfs, amstext, xfrac}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}{}
           \begin{figure}
               \centering
                   \begin{tikzpicture}
                       \begin{scope}[fill opacity = .5, text opacity = 1]
            \draw[fill = Green!70!white, even odd rule] (5, -2) rectangle (-3.5, 2) (0:2cm) circle [radius = 1];
            \draw[fill = Green!70!white, draw = black, even odd rule] (0, 0) circle [radius = 1.5];
            \draw[fill = white, draw = black, even odd rule] (0:2cm) circle [radius = 1];
    
                \node at (2, 1.3) (Q) {$Q$};
                \node at (0, 1.7) (P) {$P$};
                \node at (4.7, 1.7) (E) {$E$};
                       \end{scope}
                   \end{tikzpicture}
                       \caption{Representação de $P - Q$.}
                           \label{fig9}
        \end{figure}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use for instance `\draw[fill = white, draw = black, even odd rule] (0, 0) circle [radius = 1.5];` for the second `\draw` call (the third one may be commented out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way with no magic that fills the non-substracted part of the left circle (set) in darker green than the beckground, as you appear to desire:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[Green!35!white, even odd rule]
  (5,-2) rectangle (-3.5,2)
  (0:2cm) circle[radius = 1];
\fill[Green!60!white] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5];
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black] (0:2cm) circle [radius=1];
\draw[black] (0, 0) circle [radius=1.5];

\node at (2, 1.3) (Q) {$Q$};
\node at (0, 1.7) (P) {$P$};
\node at (4.7, 1.7) (E) {$E$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another way using clipping to fill the intersection in white:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[Green!35!white, even odd rule]
  (5,-2) rectangle (-3.5,2)
  (0:2cm) circle [radius=1];
\filldraw[fill=Green!60!white, draw=black] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5];

\begin{scope}
  \clip (0:2cm) circle[radius=1];
  \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5];
\end{scope}

\draw[black] (0:2cm) circle [radius=1];
\node at (2, 1.3) (Q) {$Q$};
\node at (0, 1.7) (P) {$P$};
\node at (4.7, 1.7) (E) {$E$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With this one, you can simply edit the `fill=white` to fill the intersection of both sets with the color of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

This is just for fun, and to provide you with a couple of standard tricks that are collected from various posts (and linked, of course). There is the possibility to have an `even odd clip` and to reuse paths. Unfortunately the "official" version that got implemented via `use path` does not always do what we want so there is also the `reuse path`, which allows us to recycle a path that has been previously stored in a macro via `save path`. In general, this tool box can be used to draw any Venn diagram rather conveniently, and these tools have also been collected in the [experimental Ti*k*Z library `venn`](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/Venn), which I am however not using here. With the `even odd clip` we can fill everything but the `Q` circle.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
% based on
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/194703
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448920/194703
\makeatletter 
\tikzset{
  reuse path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}},
  even odd clip/.code={\pgfseteorule}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another Venn diagram}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity = .5]
   \draw[save path=\pathE]  (-3.5, -2) rectangle (5, 2);
   \draw[save path=\pathQ]  (0, 0) circle [radius = 1.5];
   \draw[save path=\pathP] (0:2cm) circle [radius = 1];
   \clip[even odd clip,reuse path=\pathP]  (-3.5, -2) -|(5, 2) -| cycle;
   \fill[Green!70!white,use path=\pathE]; 
   \fill[Green!70!white,use path=\pathQ];
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2, 1.3) (Q) {$Q$};
  \node at (0, 1.7) (P) {$P$};
  \path (5, 2)  node[below left](E) {$E$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Representa\c{c}\~ao de $P - Q$.}
 \label{fig9}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]