# How to improve this stereographic projection

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying to draw the stereographic projection in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (3,-0.25);
            \coordinate (P) at (0,2);
            \draw (0,0) circle (2);
            \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and 0.5);
            \draw (-4.5,-1) -- (3.5,-1) -- (4.5,1) node[anchor=south east] {\scriptsize$ z=0 $} -- (-3.5,1) -- cycle;
            \draw (A) -- (P) coordinate[pos=0.47](B);
            \path (A) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=below:{\scriptsize$ P(x,y,0) $}]{};
            \path (B) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=left:{\scriptsize$ (\xi,\eta,\zeta) $}]{};
            \path (P) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=above:{\scriptsize$ (0,0,1) $}]{};
            \draw [dashed] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I want to acheive are dotted lines along the red lines in the following picture thus generated:
[image]

Also, I want to add another dotted line along the blue line which not there in the MWE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to draw the dashed and solid parts in separate paths, so using `arc`s instead of `circle`s for the arced paths.

The 30 degree angle was found by trial and error, but it could be calculated if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz which loads pgf
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (3,-0.25);
            \coordinate (P) at (0,2);

            \draw (0:2cm)   arc[radius=2cm,start angle=0,end angle=180]
                  (210:2cm) arc[radius=2cm,start angle=210,end angle=330];
            \draw (180:2cm) arc[x radius=2cm, y radius=0.5cm, start angle=180,end angle=360];

            \draw [dashed] (210:2cm) 
                  arc[start angle=210,delta angle=-30,radius=2cm]
                  arc[start angle=180,delta angle=-180,x radius=2cm,y radius=0.5cm]
                  arc[start angle=0,delta angle=-30,radius=2cm];

            \draw [dashed] (80:2cm and 0.5cm) -- (260:2cm and 0.5cm);
            \draw [dashed] (150:2cm) coordinate(ul) -- (30:2cm) coordinate(ur);

            \draw (-4.5,-1) -- (3.5,-1) -- (4.5,1) node[anchor=south east] {\scriptsize$ z=0 $} -- (ur) (ul) -- (-3.5,1) -- (-4.5,-1);

            \draw (A) -- (P) coordinate[pos=0.47](B);
            \path (A) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=below:{\scriptsize$ P(x,y,0) $}]{};
            \path (B) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=left:{\scriptsize$ (\xi,\eta,\zeta) $}]{};
            \path (P) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=above:{\scriptsize$ (0,0,1) $}]{};
            \draw [dashed] (-2,0) -- (2,0);

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question is misunderstood. I need to have dotted lines **replacing** the lines generated by the codes in the MWE. The places where I need the dotted lines are mentioned by the red dashes in the attached picture. And the blue line is absent in the MWE.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Sorry, I misunderstood. Anyways, the same principle can be used, in principle just do the same thing to draw the segments which should be black. Will update in a bit. I don't understand what you mean about the blue line. It's drawn in my code. If you don't want it to be blue, just remove the colour specification.

Comment: The blue line is not there in the code, so that is why I have marked it with another colour. The entire diagram will not have any coloured lines.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Well as I said, then you just needed to remove `blue`. Anyways, I updated the code.

Comment: Ah! This is working fine now. Just another question. Can you please tell me how to extract the coordinates of `B` _without_ drawing the line `AP`? I want to make the line segment `PB` a dashed one.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Use `\path (A) -- (P) coordinate[pos=0.47](B);` and then `\draw  (A) -- (B); \draw [dashed] (B) -- (P);`

Comment: BTW, you might want to make the dashed lines inside the sphere match (parallel) the edges of the parallelogram.

Comment: Dr. T.Torbjørn ! In your drawing, the center of the Sphere goes through the plane, if possible, push the Sphere into the plane and redraw it.

Comment: @HuaLuogeng I don't really understand what you want to do ... (And drop the dr. please :) )

Answer (score 10):

This is an orthographic projection of a stereographic projection. That is, 3d coordinate with an actual stereographic projection are used and projected on the screen via an orthographic projection. The dashed lines are achieved with an orgy of clips and reverse clips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% based on 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/194703 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448920/194703 
\makeatletter 
\tikzset{ 
reuse path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}} 
} 
\tikzset{even odd clip/.code={\pgfseteorule}, 
protect/.code={ 
\clip[overlay,even odd clip,reuse path=#1] 
(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east)
%(-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)
; 
}} 
\makeatother 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myaz}{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
        stereox(\x,\y)=2*\x/(1+\x*\x+\y*\y);%
        stereoy(\x,\y)=2*\y/(1+\x*\x+\y*\y);%
        stereoz(\x,\y)=(-1+\x*\x+\y*\y)/(1+\x*\x+\y*\y);},scale=2.5,
        line join=round,line cap=round,
        dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
 \path[save path=\pathSphere] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
 \begin{scope}[3d view={\myaz}{15}]
  \draw (-2,2) -- (-2,-2) coordinate (bl) -- (2,-2) coordinate (br)-- (2,2)
  node[above left]{$z=0$};
  \begin{scope}
   \tikzset{protect=\pathSphere}
   \draw (-2,2) -- (2,2);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
   \clip[reuse path=\pathSphere];
   \draw[dashed] (-2,2) -- (2,2);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \draw[dashed] (\myaz:1) arc[start angle=\myaz,end angle=\myaz+180,radius=1];
   \draw (\myaz:1) arc[start angle=\myaz,end angle=\myaz-180,radius=1];
   \path[save path=\pathPlane] (\myaz:2) -- (\myaz+180:2) --(bl) -- (br) -- cycle;
   \begin{scope}
    \clip[use path=\pathPlane];
    \draw[dashed,use path=\pathSphere];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{protect=\pathPlane}
    \draw[use path=\pathSphere];
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \draw (1.5,-1,0) node[dot,label=below:{$P(x,y,0)$}]{}
  -- ({stereox(1.5,-1)},{stereoy(1.5,-1)},{stereoz(1.5,-1)})
   node[dot,label=below left:{$(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$}](I){};
  \draw[dashed] (I) -- (0,0,1) node[dot,label=above:{$(0,0,1)$}]{}; 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can vary the view parameters and coordinates of the point on the plane. (This is all packed in one animation but the parameters can be varied separately.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
% based on 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/194703 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448920/194703 
\makeatletter 
\tikzset{ 
reuse path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}} 
} 
\tikzset{even odd clip/.code={\pgfseteorule}, 
protect/.code={ 
\clip[overlay,even odd clip,reuse path=#1] 
(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east)
; 
}} 
\makeatother 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myaz}{10+10*sin(\X)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
        stereox(\x,\y)=2*\x/(1+\x*\x+\y*\y);%
        stereoy(\x,\y)=2*\y/(1+\x*\x+\y*\y);%
        stereoz(\x,\y)=(-1+\x*\x+\y*\y)/(1+\x*\x+\y*\y);
        Px=1.75+0.5*sin(2*\X);Py=-1.5+0.5*cos(2*\X);amax=2.5;},scale=2.5,
        line join=round,line cap=round,
        dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
 \pgfdeclarelayer{background} 
 \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
 \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-3.5,-2) rectangle (3.5,2);
 \path[save path=\pathSphere,ball color=gray,fill opacity=0.6] 
    (0,0) circle[radius=1];
 \begin{scope}[3d view={\myaz}{15}]
  \draw (-amax,amax) -- (-amax,-amax) coordinate (bl) -- (amax,-amax) 
  coordinate (br)-- (amax,amax)
  node[above left]{$z=0$};
  \begin{scope}
   \tikzset{protect=\pathSphere}
   \draw (-amax,amax) -- (amax,amax);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
   \clip[reuse path=\pathSphere];
   \draw[dashed] (-amax,amax) -- (amax,amax);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \draw[dashed] (\myaz:1) arc[start angle=\myaz,end angle=\myaz+180,radius=1];
   \draw (\myaz:1) arc[start angle=\myaz,end angle=\myaz-180,radius=1];
   \path[save path=\pathPlane] (\myaz:amax) -- (\myaz+180:amax) --(bl) -- (br) -- cycle;
   \begin{scope}
   %\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}   
    \clip[use path=\pathPlane];
    \draw[dashed,use path=\pathSphere];
   %\end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{protect=\pathPlane}
    \draw[use path=\pathSphere];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \fill[blue!30,fill opacity=0.6]
     (\myaz:1) arc[start angle=\myaz,end angle=\myaz-180,radius=1]
     -- (-amax,0) -- (-amax,amax) -- (amax,amax) -- (amax,0) -- cycle;
   \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fill[blue!30,fill opacity=0.6]
     (\myaz:1) arc[start angle=\myaz,end angle=\myaz-180,radius=1]
     -- (-amax,0) -- (-amax,-amax) -- (amax,-amax) -- (amax,0) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \draw (Px,Py,0) node[dot,label=below:{$P(x,y,0)$}]{}
  -- ({stereox(Px,Py)},{stereoy(Px,-1)},{stereoz(Px,Py)})
   node[dot,label=below left:{$(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$}](I){};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
   \draw[dashed] (I) -- (0,0,1) node[dot,label=above:{$(0,0,1)$}]{};
  \end{pgfonlayer} 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, your answer looks even more charming but the code is not compiling! Should I update the question with the error messages?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul You can. (If I had to bet I'd say you have an older TeX installation and `perspective` is not available there.)

Comment: That is true. I figured it out. Let me update it and will refer back to you tomorrow. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: How was the animation produced from the LaTeX/TikZ output, which is just a series of static frames?