# Format line properties when it appears behind another object in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I am using the `tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere` package to draw circles of a sphere using tikz-3dplot. Consider the following MWE from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere}
\begin{document}
  \centering
  \def\r{3}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \draw[tdplot_screen_coords,thin,black!30] (0,0,0) circle (\r);
    \foreach \a in {-75,-60,...,75}
      {\tdplotCsDrawLatCircle[thin,black!29]{\r}{\a}}
    \foreach \a in {0,15,...,165}
      {\tdplotCsDrawLonCircle[thin,black!29]{\r}{\a}}

    \tdplotCsDrawGreatCircle[red,thick,/.style={opacity=0}]{4}{105}{-23.5}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates the following image

[image]

How can I get the dashed red line to appear when it is *only* behind the sphere. I.e. in this case I have chosen a radii for the red circle that is larger than that of the sphere.

Comment: would [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539956/how-can-i-draw-sphere-cut-by-plane-by-using-tikz-3dplot) help?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily, the linked post appears to address exactly what I'm asking, though It's not clear how to use it in this case.

Comment: Does the provided answer help? If yes, then maybe accept it. If not, then maybe leave a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

**Updated version**

My answer is not the shortest and maybe some of the elements that I
use are already defined in a library; I am not aware of.

The drawing is made in three steps: 1) the 3D point of view, 2) the
sphere and 3) the circles (two on the sphere and a third one lying in
the plane of the small circle on the sphere and having the same
center).  Now the sphere is constructed through meridians and
parallels, i.e. circles, too.

Every circle is constructed as a `pic` to have a cleaner code.

The hidden points on the sphere are detected by computing the inner
product between the viewer vector and the position vector of the
point.  See the function `opacityOnS`.

The points inside the sphere or behind the sphere are detected by a
mixture of inner products and norm comparisons.  See the function
`behindS`.

Some more explanations about the elements are used in these three
steps.

0. In TikZ, the coordinate plane *Oxy* corresponds to the screen and *Oz*
   points outside the screen, towards the viewer.
1. The observer is represented by the vector defined by `\tox`, `\toy`,
   and `\toz` introduced through the key `view` with arguments the
   longitude and the latitude. When both are zero, the vector is *(0,0,1)*.
2. The various circles have similar codes as `pic` objects.  I
   preferred to redefine them depending on the number of arguments
   needed.  But all these functions make the file `tikZSphere.sty` rather long.
3. The opacity and its opposite are
   controlled through the keys `unseenS` and `seenS`.
4. The sphere radius is controlled through the key `radiusS`.  The default value is 1.

**Remark.** I don't address the question regarding how two circles on
the sphere intersect.  I imagine a solution, but it is clumsy; I need
to define the circles (or parts of them) as whole elements (through
the `\path` command) to be able to use the option `name path`
afterward.  Maybe some developments as those proposed by *user121799*
in
[Embed a graph on a Sphere with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436669/embed-a-graph-on-a-sphere-with-tikz/436711#436711)
would be useful, but they are above my knowledge.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\usepackage{tikZSphere}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[view={-35}{27}, radiusS=2.5]
  % meridians and parallels
  \begin{scope}[black!50, seenS=.7, unseenS=.25, very thin]
    \foreach \l in {15, 30, ..., 360}{ \path pic {meridian={\l}}; }
    \foreach \l in {-75, -60, ..., 75}{ \path pic {parallel={\l}}; }
  \end{scope}
  
  \path[unseenS=.32] pic[magenta, thick] {bigCircleOnS={80:70}};
  \path[unseenS=.32] pic[blue, thick] {circleOnS={80:70 at distance -.85}};
  \path[unseenS=.25] pic[blue, thick] {circle3d={80:70:4 at distance -.85}};
  
  \path[seenS=.9] pic[orange] {axesForS={1.75}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the file `tikZsphere.sty`:

```
\tikzset{%
  view/.style 2 args={%
    z={({-sin(#1)}, {-cos(#1)*sin(#2)})},
    x={({cos(#1)}, {-sin(#1)*sin(#2)})},
    y={(0, {cos(#2)})},
    evaluate={%
      \tox={sin(#1)*cos(#2)};
      \toy={sin(#2)};
      \toz={cos(#1)*cos(#2)};
    }
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  seenS/.store in=\seenS,
  seenS=1
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  unseenS/.store in=\unseenS,
  unseenS=.2
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  radiusS/.store in=\radiusS,
  radiusS=1
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  samplesCOnS/.store in=\samplesCOnS,
  samplesCOnS=36
}

\tikzmath{%  opacities and samples
  function opacityOnS(\px, \py, \pz) {%
    \res = \px*\tox + \py*\toy + \pz*\toz; % inner product of posV and obsrerver
    if \res>0 then {return \seenS;} else {return \unseenS;};
  };
  function behindS(\px, \py, \pz, \r) {%
    \sppo = \px*\tox + \py*\toy + \pz*\toz; % inner product of pos.vect and obsrerver
    \npsq = \px*\px + \py*\py + \pz*\pz; % norm of pos.vect^2
    \nvsq = \npsq -\sppo*\sppo; % norm of pos,vect's projection^2
    if \sppo<0 then {%
      if \nvsq -\r*\r<.05 then {return \unseenS;} else {return \seenS;};
    } else {%
      if \npsq -\r*\r<.05 then {return \unseenS;} else {return \seenS;};
    };
  };
  function stepsCOnS(\r, \k) {return ceil(\r*(\k-6)/\radiusS+6);};
}

\tikzset{
  pics/axesForS/.style={%
    code={
      \tikzmath{%
        real \b;
        \b = {#1*\radiusS};
      }
      \foreach \i in {.1, .2, ..., \b}{%
        \draw[opacity={behindS(\i-.05, 0, 0, \radiusS)}] (\i-.1, 0, 0) -- (\i, 0, 0);
        \path (\b, 0, 0) ++(.4, 0, 0) node[scale=.9] {$x$};
        \draw[opacity={behindS(0, \i-.05, 0, \radiusS)}] (0, \i-.1, 0) -- (0, \i, 0);
        \path (0, \b, 0) ++(0, .4, 0) node[scale=.9] {$y$};
        \draw[opacity={behindS(0, 0, \i-.05, \radiusS)}] (0, 0, \i-.1) -- (0, 0, \i);
        \path (0, 0, \b) ++(0, 0, .4) node[scale=.9] {$z$};
      }
    }
  },
  pics/meridian/.style = {% longitude, number of points
    code={
      \tikzmath{
        real \pax, \pay, \paz, \pbx, \pby, \pbz, \cosl, \sinl;
        integer \N;
        \cosl = \radiusS*cos(#1);
        \sinl = \radiusS*sin(#1);
        \N = int(\samplesCOnS/2);
      }
      \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \bz using {180*(\k/\N -.5)},
      evaluate=\k as \az using {180*((\k-1)/\N -.5)}] in {1, ..., \N}{
        \tikzmath{
          \pax = \cosl*cos(\az);
          \pay = \radiusS*sin(\az);
          \paz = \sinl*cos(\az);
          \pbx = \cosl*cos(\bz);
          \pby = \radiusS*sin(\bz);
          \pbz = \sinl*cos(\bz);
        }
        \draw[opacity={opacityOnS(\pax, \pay, \paz)}]
        (\pax, \pay, \paz) -- (\pbx, \pby, \pbz);
      }
    }
  },
  pics/parallel/.style = {% latitude, number of points
    code={
      \tikzmath{
        integer \N;
        real \pax, \pay, \paz, \pbx, \pby, \pbz, \cosl, \sinl;
        \cosl = \radiusS*cos(#1);
        \sinl = \radiusS*sin(#1);
        \N = stepsCOnS(\radiusS*cos(#1), \samplesCOnS);
      }
      \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \by using {360*(\j/\N)},
      evaluate=\j as \ay using {360*((\j-1)/\N)}] in {1, ..., \N}{
        \tikzmath{
          \pax = cos(\ay)*\cosl;
          \paz = sin(\ay)*\cosl;
          \pbx = cos(\by)*\cosl;
          \pbz = sin(\by)*\cosl;
        }
        \draw[opacity={opacityOnS(\pbx, \sinl, \pbz)}]
        (\pax, \sinl, \paz) -- (\pbx, \sinl, \pbz);
      }
    }
  }
}


%%%% other circles

\tikzmath{
  function Cx(\t) {
    return \r*\ux*cos(\t) + \r*\vx*sin(\t) + \d*\nx;
  };  
  function Cy(\t) {
    return \r*\vy*sin(\t) + \d*\ny;
  };  
  function Cz(\t) {
    return \r*\uz*cos(\t) + \r*\vz*sin(\t) + \d*\nz;
  };
}
\tikzset{
  pics/circle3d/.style args={#1:#2:#3 at distance #4}{% 
    code={
      \tikzmath{
        integer \N;
        \N = {stepsCOnS(\radiusS, 3*\samplesCOnS)};
        \nx = cos(#2)*sin(#1);
        \ny = sin(#2);
        \nz = cos(#2)*cos(#1);
        \ux = cos(#1);
        \uz = -sin(#1);
        \vx = -sin(#2)*sin(#1);
        \vy = cos(#2);
        \vz = -sin(#2)*cos(#1);
        \d = #4;
        \r = #3;
      }
      \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \t using {360*(\j/\N)},
      evaluate=\j as \s using {360*((\j-1)/\N)}] in {1, ..., \N}{
        \tikzmath{
          \pax = Cx(\s); 
          \pay = Cy(\s);
          \paz = Cz(\s);
          \pbx = Cx(\t);
          \pby = Cy(\t);
          \pbz = Cz(\t);
        }
        \draw[opacity={%
          behindS((\pax+\pbx)/2, (\pay+\pby)/2, (\paz+\pbz)/2, \radiusS)}]
        (\pax, \pay, \paz) -- (\pbx, \pby, \pbz);
      }
    }    
  },
  pics/bigCircleOnS/.style args={#1:#2}{% 
    code={
      \tikzmath{
        integer \N;
        \N = {stepsCOnS(\radiusS, \samplesCOnS)};
        \nx = cos(#2)*sin(#1);
        \ny = sin(#2);
        \nz = cos(#2)*cos(#1);
        \ux = cos(#1);
        \uz = -sin(#1);
        \vx = -sin(#2)*sin(#1);
        \vy = cos(#2);
        \vz = -sin(#2)*cos(#1);
        \d = 0;
        \r = \radiusS;
      }
      \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \t using {360*(\j/\N)},
      evaluate=\j as \s using {360*((\j-1)/\N)}] in {1, ..., \N}{
        \tikzmath{
          \pax = Cx(\s); 
          \pay = Cy(\s);
          \paz = Cz(\s);
          \pbx = Cx(\t);
          \pby = Cy(\t);
          \pbz = Cz(\t);
        }
        \draw[opacity={opacityOnS((\pax+\pbx)/2, (\pay+\pby)/2, (\paz+\pbz)/2)}]
        (\pax, \pay, \paz) -- (\pbx, \pby, \pbz);
      }
    }    
  },
  pics/bigCircleOnS/.default={0:90},
  pics/circleOnS/.style args={#1:#2 at distance#3}{% 
    code={
      \tikzmath{
        integer \N;
        \N = {stepsCOnS(\radiusS, \samplesCOnS)};
        \nx = cos(#2)*sin(#1);
        \ny = sin(#2);
        \nz = cos(#2)*cos(#1);
        \ux = cos(#1);
        \uz = -sin(#1);
        \vx = -sin(#2)*sin(#1);
        \vy = cos(#2);
        \vz = -sin(#2)*cos(#1);
        \d = #3;
        \r = sqrt(\radiusS*\radiusS-\d*\d);
      }
      \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \t using {360*(\j/\N)},
      evaluate=\j as \s using {360*((\j-1)/\N)}] in {1, ..., \N}{
        \tikzmath{
          \pax = Cx(\s); 
          \pay = Cy(\s);
          \paz = Cz(\s);
          \pbx = Cx(\t);
          \pby = Cy(\t);
          \pbz = Cz(\t);
        }
        \draw[opacity={opacityOnS((\pax+\pbx)/2, (\pay+\pby)/2, (\paz+\pbz)/2)}]
        (\pax, \pay, \paz) -- (\pbx, \pby, \pbz);
      }
    }    
  }
```

**The image from the initial version of the answer**
[image]

Comment: Could you extend the red and purple lines so that their radii are larger than the sphere? I specifically, want to see dashing when the line goes behind the sphere.

Comment: "Yes" for the circles' radii.  It is sufficient to apply a homothety in the plane of the circle when the points are defined.

Comment: As for the "going behind" when the curve is not placed on the sphere, this is another story.  The program, as it is, cannot handle this situation.  Probably,  one should consider the segment form a small segment of the curve to the viewer and study the intersection with the sphere...

Comment: Hi @Sid.  Working on something else, I came out with a way to answering your question.  Are you still interested?  The code follows the idea I was talking about in the message above.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, yes I am still interested in the question. Might also be useful for other Stack users. Would you be able to upload it?

Comment: Of course, I can.  But how should I do it? Should I replace the old answer, or update it.  In the latter case, it will become too long in my opinion.

Comment: since it is a related question, I advise you add an update and add your solution after your current solution. If you feel the answer is distinctly different in method, you can add a separate answer to this question (although I'm not sure that's possible).

Answer (score 0):

This is just for the part about getting the dashed line behind the sphere.  I don't know where the `tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere` is from so I can't test with that.  Instead, I've drawn the outline of a sphere (which is an ellipse) and used that.

This uses the [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library to split the orbital path where it intersects with the boundary path, and then renders the pieces with different styles.

[image: Orbit split as it passes behind a boundary circle]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551460/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[
  rotate=45,
  spath/save=boundary
] (0,0) circle[
  x radius={3*sqrt(1 + 2*.385^2)},
  y radius=3
];

\path[
  spath/save=orbital,
  y = {(1,0,0)},
  x = {(0,0,1)}
] (0,0) circle[radius=5];

\tikzset{
  spath/remove empty components={orbital},
  spath/split at intersections with={orbital}{boundary},
  spath/join components={orbital}{1,4},
  spath/get components of={orbital}\cpts
}

\draw[
  red,
  ultra thick,
  dashed,
  spath/use=\getComponentOf\cpts{1}
];

\draw[
  blue,
  ultra thick,
  spath/use=boundary];

\draw[
  red,
  ultra thick,
  spath/use=\getComponentOf\cpts{2}
];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```